# Как добавить класс с задержкой к элементам, которые попали в viewport блока?

Tags: jquery

Задача добавить класс с задержкой к елементам, которые находятся в полезрения родительского блока. Если скроллить просто вниз не останавливаясь. То выглядит якобы хорошо. Но если остановится и снова скроллить, то скрипт начинает заново отрабатываться с первого элемента. Как сделать чтобы он продолжил отрабатывать, а не начинал отрабатывать заново? Пример кода ниже:

```js
$('.viewport').scroll( function(){
       $('.element').each( function(i, e){
          var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight(),
              bottom_of_window = $('.viewport').scrollTop() + $('.viewport').height();
              if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object){ 
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(e).css('opacity', '1');
                }, i * 1000);
                                   
            }
            
        }); 
    
    });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  background: #95B8D1;
  font-family: "Pt Sans", sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  min-height: 100vh
}
.viewport {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  color: #747474;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.element {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="viewport">
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id ius aperiri reformidans mediocritatem. Ei cum quando vocibus, id numquam labores veritus usu.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скроллишь - событие `scroll` запускается многократно. Добавьте второй строкой `console.log('0');` и посмотрите в консоль. Ваша функция исполняется десятки раз.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю.. Как это "улучшить" можно?

Comment: вам не надо запускать на `scroll` метод `each`, который заново перебирает все элементы. Полагаю при событии `scroll` надо проверять видимость элементов, виден - не трогать, не виден - показать.